# Nvidia GeForce GTX 765M + TurboVNC

Tags: vnc, opengl

I’m trying to remotely render CARLA using VirtualGL and TurboVNC and it keeps using MesaGL (in Linux Ubuntu 20). I did try a remote VNC server and a local one and I got the same problem. “nvidia-settings” doesn’t detect any graphic accelerator inside the VNC session but works well outside of it. I did configure the server using: "vglserver_config" as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this setup doesn't work. So I switched to 'x11vnc' server which is a way better solution because it renders on the local X server.